# Rails - using url: versus href: when sending a path to the controller. What makes them different?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, checkbox, href

This is a followup question to an earlier one of mine:
[Rails 5 - use collection_radio_buttons to open a partial with nested models?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46352294/rails-5-use-collection-radio-buttons-to-open-a-partial-with-nested-models/46771578#46771578)

We were able to make a `radio_button` send a request to open a partial with content related to the button being clicked. (yay!) The main change, AFAIK, was when we replaced `href:` with `url:` in the button's arguments.

**What I don't understand yet is how these two things differ in their execution.**

Here's the snippets of each version:

```
<% System.all.each do |rt| %>
  <label>
    <%= f.radio_button :system_id, rt.id, data:{:remote => true, 'data-target' => 
   '@applicationList'}, href: system_applications_path(:system_id => rt.id, 
   :schedule_id => params['id']), class: 'remote-input', onclick: 
   "#applicationsList" %>
  </label>
<% end %>
```

Versus:

```
<% @systems.each do |a|
  <label class="btn btn-sm btn-default">
    <%= f.radio_button :system_id, a.id, :data => {url:system_applications_path(:system_id 
    => a.id, :schedule_id => params['id']), 'data-target' => '#applicationList'+a.id.to_s,
    :remote => true} %>
    <%= a.system_nm %>
  </label>
<% end %>
```

In particular (the `rt` and `a` are really the same thing, just in different loops):

```
 href: system_applications_path(:system_id => rt.id, :schedule_id => params['id'])
```

vs:

```
 url: system_applications_path(:system_id => a.id, :schedule_id => params['id'])
```

Answer (score 0):

In a nutshell (and this insight came from a related question which you can probably see in the sidebar to the right) --

`url:` means "this is the data to use for the value;
and `href:` means "go to this location."

So when you click on the button using `url:`, it takes that value and uses it in whichever method you're using.  If the button uses `href:` instead, it immediately attempts to go to wherever `href` is pointing.

This should be RoR 101-level stuff, but I simply missed it.